# unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle in release apk

Tags: react-native, apk, release

This error occurs in only release APK. it's work fine in debug.

Please help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

[Please review attached screenshot for error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CLU2.png)

Answer (score 5):

try following step

If not than (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets.

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>       index.js --bundle-output
>       android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>       android/app/src/main/res
>
> react-native run-android

I hope it help full for you